# Can you link to server side includes from another site?

Tags: server-side-includes

I have a search template on PicoSearch and our design uses a server side include to load the menu so I'm wondering if I can link to the server side include on our server from the search template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. If you have full control of the environment in question, you can set up a method (like a service) to feed the information for the other application, but even if you successfully figure out how to #include from another site, you will end up with warnings for your end users, which is not very nice looking for the user.

Comment: Thanks. I think I knew the answer as I was typing it, but I was hoping there was something that could be done. It would be easy to include the code (just the actual code) instead of the include if it weren't database driven on top.

Comment: I thought maybe there would be a way to have the menu be generated on our server and somehow include the data on the search template, but I have no control over the search server at all, so I guess I'll just create a dummy to fill in the design.

Comment: I figured out another way. I don't need the server side include, but I can still use my ASP code and just connect it to our server, problem solved!